# Обработка исключения System.Threading.ThreadAbortException

Tags: asp.net, c#

Как обработать исключение System.Threading.ThreadAbortException, авторизация формой asp.net?

Пытаюсь реализовать проверку подлинности на основе форм в приложении ASP.NET с помощью C#.NET,  [пример](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301240). При отладке Visual Studio 2008 выдаёт следующее:

> `Первый этап обработки исключения типа "System.Threading.ThreadAbortException" в приложении mscorlib.dll
> В System.Threading.ThreadAbortException произошло необработанное в коде пользователя исключение типа mscorlib.dll.`

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как это исправить?

Answer (score 1):

`FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage` вызывает мгновенный редирект -  [Response.Redirect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/a8wa7sdt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) параметром `End=true`.

Мгновенный редирект в ASP.NET реализован через выбрасывание исключения `System.Threading.ThreadAbortException`. Это сделано намеренно, чтобы прекратить обработку запроса и предотвратить выполнение любого последующего кода.

Это исключение лучше игнорировать - снять для него чексбокс в колонке `Thrown` в меню `Debug / Exceptions`

Answer (score 0):

[ThreadAbortException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.threadabortexception(VS.90).aspx)

> При вызове метода Abort для уничтожения потока, общеязыковая среда выполнения выдает исключение ThreadAbortException. Исключение ThreadAbortException является особым исключением, которое может быть перехвачено, но снова возникает в конце блока catch. При возникновении этого исключения среда выполнения перед тем, как завершить поток, выполняет все блоки finally.

```
    try {
        // ...
    }
    catch(ThreadAbortException e) {
        Thread.ResetAbort();
    }
```

Comment: Метод Abort явно не вызывается, подскажите, как перехватить и обработать это исключение?

Comment: Данное исключение вызывает эта строка  FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(txtUserName.Value,
  chkPersistCookie.Checked);
Редиректа не происходит, подскажите, как исправить?